# Insert routes programmatically in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm creating an engine that needs to insert some routes into the application's router.  For this particular gem, I'd rather not application's routes.rb if possible.  **Is there a way to insert routes at a particular location in the router via code?**  I'm looking for an API that does something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.insert("resources :foos", :before => "some string in routes.rb")
```

If I create a config/routes.rb inside the engine and define some routes, this kind of works.  Rails is smart enough to mix the engine's routes into the application's routes, but it tacks them on at the end of the route list.  I need them to appear at the beginning so the engine's routes take priority.

I'm aware that I can namespace the routes by mounting the engine in the application's routes.rb, but this creates a routing structure that I don't really want.  I want the engine's routes to look they are a part of the application by defining some routes in the actual application.

I have a workaround which is to add the following to the application's routes.rb.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    MyEngine.setup_routes(self)
    #...other routes below
end
```

MyEngine.setup_routes looks like

```
def self.setup_routes(map)
  map.get 'a_path', :to => 'a_controller#a_path'
end
```

This at least allows me to control the point where the routes get defined in the application's route list, but the user still has to manually update his routes.rb (or I have to build an installer that does it).  It seems like there should be a way to tell rails to tack some routes onto the start of the route list...

Comment: http://experiments.openhood.com/rails/rails%203/2010/07/20/add-routes-at-runtime-rails-3/ - Something like that?

Comment: How about doing something like http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:devise_for - the user still needs to update their routes but its a one liner and gives alot of flexibity.

Comment: @Trinculo - Thanks for that link.  That looks like a potential solution.

Comment: @papirtiger - I believe Devise is essentially mounting the engine behind the scenes which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Trinculo can confirm that solution does not work in 4.14. route doesn't get saved to list for some reason.